# Cleanest way to toggle class in list through setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, setinterval

I would like to toggle an 'active' class in a list of elements:

```
<div ref="gallery" class="slider">
  <div class="slide active">
  <div class="slide">
  <div class="slide">
</div>
```

Using Vue and Vanilla JS

```
Slider() {
  const slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slider')
  for (const slide of slider) {
    setInterval(function () {
      const current = slide.querySelector('.active')
      current.classList.remove('active')
      const next = current.nextElementSibling || slide.firstElementChild
      next.classList.add('active')
    }, 5000)
  }
}
```

While the above code *does* work, I feel it is not as clean as it could be.

Also, and mainly, if I target the slider using a Vue ref like:

```
const slider = this.$refs.gallery
```

it stops working

---

tony19 answer led me to reduce the code even further using Nuxt:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      activeIndex: 0,
      slides: [
        { id: 1, text: 'Slide 1' },
        { id: 2, text: 'Slide 2' },              
        { id: 3, text: 'Slide 3' },
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.Slider()
  },
  methods: {
    Slider() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.activeIndex = (this.activeIndex + 1) % this.slides.length
      }, 3000)
    }
  }   
}

<template>
  <div class="slider">
    <div v-for="(slide, index) in slides"
      :key="slide.id"
      :class="['slide', { active: index === activeIndex }]">
      {{ slide.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a class binding that sets `class` to `active` based on the active index:

1. Declare an `activeIndex` property to hold the active index.
2. In the `mounted` hook, use `setInterval()` with a callback that increments `activeIndex`. Track the timer ID from `setInterval()` so that we can stop the timer later.
3. In the `unmounted` hook, stop the interval timer with `clearInterval()` on the timer ID.
4. Use the [object syntax for class bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-to-objects) to bind an `active` class only when the `activeIndex` matches the slide's index from `v-for`.

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

let timerId = -1
1️⃣
const activeIndex = ref(0)
const slides = ref([
  { id: 1, text: 'Slide 1' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Slide 2' },
  { id: 3, text: 'Slide 3' },
])

2️⃣
onMounted(() => {
  timerId = setInterval(() => {
    activeIndex.value = (activeIndex.value + 1) % slides.value.length
  }, 3000)
})
3️⃣
onUnmounted(() => {
  clearInterval(timerId)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="gallery" class="slider">
    <div v-for="(slide, index) in slides"
      :key="slide.id"
      class="slide"
      4️⃣
      :class="{ active: index === activeIndex }">
      {{ slide.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-set-class-on-active-index?file=src/components/MySlides.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I made this demo in `vue.js` format as per your request. Please have a look and see if this is what you actually want to achieve.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    slideData: [{
        name: 'Slide 1',
      isActive: true
    }, {
        name: 'Slide 2',
      isActive: false    
    }, {
        name: 'Slide 3',
      isActive: false    
    }]
  },
  mounted() {
    this.slideData.forEach((obj) => {
      setInterval(() => {
        obj.isActive = !obj.isActive;
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(slider, index) in slideData" class="slide" :class="{ active: slider.isActive }">
  {{ slider.name}}
</div>
</div>
```